# arduino fingerprint scanner with bluetooth module

Tags: c++

For now I am using External Fingerprint Scanner and interfaced with Arduino Uno. I want to ask how we can use HC-06 (bluetooth module) to take value from the serial monitor and send to android apps that I developed using android studio?

[Part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4TVD.png)

[ContinuePart1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wl98.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your Bluetooth module has a UART interface using RS232 TTL (typically 5v but this device accepts 3.3v - 5v supply but the TX and RX lines must be 3.3v). It's a slave only device with default settings of 9600 bad, no parity, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit. The default name is linvor, default passcode is 1234. Attach it to your arduinos UART port (or rs232 I forget how they are labeled) after you set the port settings to match the defaults. Supply power to the device and start scanning for Bluetooth devices with your phone.

When your scanning for Bluetooth devices it will be listed with a device name of linvor. When you attempt to connect to it the passcode will need to be 1234.

After you connect you can send + receive data as if the device is a normal serial port.

Before the device is paired to anything(green led is blinking) you can program the device with the AT command (Attention). All commands are uppercase. Successful commands return OK. Commands have a 1 second window to be sent so do not try to type these in a terminal. copy+paste or send them programmatically.

AT //returns OK and proves your successfully connected

AT+BAUD1    1200
AT+BAUD2    2400
AT+BAUD3    4800
AT+BAUD4    9600
AT+BAUD5    19200
AT+BAUD6    38400
AT+BAUD7    57600
AT+BAUD8    115200

AT+NAMExxxxxx  (name can be up to 6 characters long in place of the x's in the command, ex AT+NAMElinvor)

AT+PINnnnn (replace n's with your pin, ex AT+PIN1234).

AT+VERSION (if version returns > 1.5 then there are parity commands too)

AT+PO  odd parity
AT+PN  no parity
AT+PE  even parity

Your Android apps will have to have access to Bluetooth. A good start would be the developer guide.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth

It has a nice step by step guide and example to follow.

After you have paired your Android to the device it should work as a regular serial and the led on it will be solid green and if your Android app was set up properly you should be able to communicate with your Arduino.